# Which is the file size limit of a gzip resource after which it becomes convenient to issue a new HTTP request?

Tags: http, mobile, compression, gzip

I remember an article of a couple of years ago, where someone took the time to measure where – especially on a mobile device – opening a new HTTP connection (which is expensive, but runs in parallel) is better than transferring XXX KB of a gzipped resource.

This means that there is a (heuristically defined) limit after which it becomes more convenient – from a front-end perceived performance point of view – to create more than one gzip file for your resource(s) than just bundling everything into a massive 2MB file.

I'm not able to find that article anymore, so the question is: do you know which article I am talking about and/or do you agree that such a limit exists?